# Can't access the object from the props inside created method

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I got an object from API resource and put it inside the property, then children component can't access the props's object inside created method to assign it values inside my data properties as arrays and strings

when i try to console the props from child component i found my items object inside it

"This is my parent component"

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-xl fill-height>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
        <message-box :items="source" v-if="source.length > 0"></message-box>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

```
<script>
<script>
import MessageBox from './MessageBox'
export default {
  components:{MessageBox},
  data() {
    return {
      room_id: 1,
      source: {},
    };
  },
  created(){
    var app = this;
    axios.get(`/api/room/${app.room_id}/message`)
    .then(res => app.source = res.data.data);
  }
};
</script>

</script>
```

"This is my child component"

```
<template>
    <div>
        <beautiful-chat
          :participants="participants"
          :titleImageUrl="titleImageUrl"
          :onMessageWasSent="onMessageWasSent"
          :messageList="messageList.messageList"
          :newMessagesCount="newMessagesCount"
          :isOpen="isChatOpen"
          :close="closeChat"
          :icons="icons"
          :open="openChat"
          :showEmoji="true"
          :showFile="true"
          :showTypingIndicator="showTypingIndicator"
          :colors="colors"
          :alwaysScrollToBottom="alwaysScrollToBottom"
          :messageStyling="messageStyling"
          @onType="handleOnType"
          @edit="editMessage"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import CloseIcon from "vue-beautiful-chat/src/assets/close-icon.png";
import OpenIcon from "vue-beautiful-chat/src/assets/logo-no-bg.svg";
import FileIcon from "vue-beautiful-chat/src/assets/file.svg";
import CloseIconSvg from "vue-beautiful-chat/src/assets/close.svg";
export default {
  props: ['items'],
  data() {
    return {
      room_id: 1,
      participants:[],
      messageList: [],
      limit: 7,
      busy: false,
      auth_uid: User.id(),
      titleImageUrl:
        "https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/avatars-teams/ava_0001-34.png",
      newMessagesCount: 0,
      isChatOpen: false,
      alwaysScrollToBottom: false, // when set to true always scrolls the chat to the bottom when new events are in (new message, user starts typing...)
      messageStyling: true,
      showTypingIndicator: "",
      icons: {
        open: {
          img: OpenIcon,
          name: "default"
        },
        close: {
          img: CloseIcon,
          name: "default"
        },
        file: {
          img: FileIcon,
          name: "default"
        },
        closeSvg: {
          img: CloseIconSvg,
          name: "default"
        }
      },
      colors: {
        header: {
          bg: "#4e8cff",
          text: "#ffffff"
        },
        launcher: {
          bg: "#4e8cff"
        },
        messageList: {
          bg: "#ffffff"
        },
        sentMessage: {
          bg: "#4e8cff",
          text: "#ffffff"
        },
        receivedMessage: {
          bg: "#eaeaea",
          text: "#222222"
        },
        userInput: {
          bg: "#f4f7f9",
          text: "#565867"
        }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage(text) {
      if (text.length > 0) {
        this.newMessagesCount = this.isChatOpen
          ? this.newMessagesCount
          : this.newMessagesCount + 1;
        this.onMessageWasSent({
          author: "support",
          type: "text",
          data: { text }
        });
        axios
          .post(`/api/room/${this.room_id}/message`, { body: text })
          .then(res => console.log("message sent"));
      }
    },
    onMessageWasSent(message) {
      // called when the user sends a message
      this.messageList = [...this.messageList, message];
    },
    openChat() {
      // called when the user clicks on the fab button to open the chat
      this.isChatOpen = true;
      this.newMessagesCount = 0;
    },
    closeChat() {
      // called when the user clicks on the botton to close the chat
      this.isChatOpen = false;
    },
    handleScrollToTop() {
      // called when the user scrolls message list to top
      // leverage pagination for loading another page of messages
    },
    handleOnType() {
      console.log("Emit typing event");
    },
    editMessage(message) {
      const m = this.messageList.find(m => m.id === message.id);
      m.isEdited = true;
      m.data.text = message.data.text;
    },
  },
  created(){
    // console.log(this.$props.items)
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.$props.items, child => {
        this.participants = child.participants;
        // console.log(this.participants)
        this.messageList = child.body;
        // console.log(this.messageList)
    });
  },
  computed:{
      itemarr(){
          return this.$props.items
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

"The console error is `TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined`"

"The output of my items object is `{__ob__: Observer}`"

Comment: You have some errors on the props flow. You need to declare on child component attributes :propName="propModel" and then retrieve in component with props: ['propName']

Comment: Before your API callback finishes, source will be empty, so there will be nothing to iterate over.

Comment: After my API callback, i accept its data from source property. do you mean my source property will be empty after page loading?

Comment: Can you add to the question the entire father and child components to understand the problem better, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-if` to solve your problem. You need to wait for ajax response to render child component

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-xl fill-height>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
        <message-box v-if="sourceLength > 0" :items="source"></message-box>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

```
<script>
<script>
import MessageBox from './MessageBox'
export default {
  components:{MessageBox},
  data() {
    return {
      room_id: 1,
      source: {},
    };
  },
  created(){
    var app = this;
    axios.get(`/api/room/${app.room_id}/message`)
    .then(res => app.source = res.data.data);
  },
  get sourceLength() {
    return Object.keys(this.source).length;
  }
};
</script>

</script>
```

Comment: message box is my child component so that it accepts the props items from parent via props['items'], and does my parent component also need a props value?

Comment: Update the question, you put `<message-box>` as parent component. Little confuse. Then you have `message-box` inside `beautiful-chat` right?

Comment: i have beautiful-chat inside message-box, sorry if i made confused

Comment: added `v-if="source.length > 0"` to parent and can see items with `console.log(this.$props.items)`, but the error is still `Error in created hook: "TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined"`

Comment: But you change the line `this.items.children` by `this.$props.items.children` ?

Comment: I mean on `console.log(this.$props.items)
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.items.children, child => {
        this.participants = child.participants;
        this.messageList = child.messageList;
    });`

Comment: yes i changed the created function and both `participants` and `messageList` have now data but as objects, how can i change them into array because attribute binds `:participants` and `:messageList` request me as arrays?

Comment: You only can do it by mapping child.participants and child.messageList before save. I.E: `this.participants = Object.keys(child.participants).map(index => {return child.participants[index];};`

Comment: yes fixed the problem, thank you so much for helping me, i appreciate that